# Interactive architectural diagram tools

Tags: architecture, diagram, interactive

Are there any tools that would allow me to easily create an interactive architectural diagram?

I envisage the ability to view a graphical depiction of the architecture at a high level. I would then be able to click on a specific piece of the architecture and drill into it, thus revealing a more detailed break-down of that piece. This process could then continue for as many levels as necessary.

Does anyone know of any tools that allow me to create this kind of experience? Or should I perhaps try to achieve this with Visio/Powerpoint?

Comment: Visio/Powerpoint is not really feasible IMHO. Both support drilling down via clicking. But that leaves you to manually update connections and interfaces among figures, impossible for anything non-trivial.

The canonical solution for Visio is to go to huge paper/canvas sizes and to put everything into one graph. Thats how printer manufacturers sell A1 printers to IT architects.

Comment: The nazis have closed this, but I wanted to mention https://structurizr.com/ and C4 in general. There's a great talk here: https://vimeo.com/193422891

Comment: https://icepanel.io allows for zoomable interactive architecture diagrams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use Sparx EA (Enterprise Architect).
One of the "export" options is an "HTML Report" which works in the manner you're after. 
You can zip up the resulting files and send to someone else who can then 'browse' the model.

http://www.sparxsystems.com/

Comment: +1 for Enterprise Architect. I used this extensively to reverse-engineer the class diagrams of a project. One can take higher level views going up several packages. However I don't think it's at the level of interactivity that you would look for.

Comment: +1 Looks interesting. Will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that such a tool can prove to be valuable. Indeed, this was one of our goals when we set out to develop [nWire](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/). We are not there yet, but this is something that we hope to develop and extend some day.

I believe that such a tool should be "alive" with the code and not an offline representation, because we never invest in maintaining such documents and 5 minutes later they're outdated. Hence, I don't think a Visio solution will do. I also believe in minimal user investment, plug-and-play tools.

There are some questions that needs to be addressed, though, like how to derive the architecture from the code in a way that would make sense, what are the zoom levels, etc. I'm not sure one generic solution can fit all projects, you will want to customize it to understand your specific architecture.

If you have more thoughts and ideas around this, I would love to hear them. Either post them here or email me to zviki at nwiresoftware.com.

Answer (score 0):

The new Architecture tools in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition can do exactly this. You can interactively filter the view. See some of the MSDN topics under "Modeling the Application", "[Exploring Existing Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409365%28VS.100%29.aspx)".

Comment: Don't those tools assume that your entire system is contained within a VS project? And aren't they rather code-centric? What about non-MS tech? What about extraneous infrastructure such as load balancers that you want in your diagram?